# Obtaining a "Supervisa" for Canada from outside your home country?

Tags: visas, canada

Can one apply for the parents/grandparents supervisa from -

outside their home country?

from within Canada while on a visitor visa?

Answer (score 4):

Canada's parent and grandparent super visa is a temporary resident visa (visitor visa) which allows visitors to stay up to two years on each entry.

Canada requires applicants for visitor visas to [apply outside Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/apply-where.asp), either in their home country, or from a country which they have been admitted for a period of at least one year.

> For all other applications *[other than permanent residence]* you must select the visa office that serves your country of nationality or the country where you have been legally admitted for at least one year.

The only exception allowing an application from within Canada is if the applicant has entered Canada on a student or work permit. (But it seems unlikely that such a person would need or qualify for a parent and grandparent super visa.)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, temporary resident visa applications (incl. supervisas) may be submitted in any country where you are staying legally. Online application is recommended.

> **I am currently living in or visiting a country that I am not a citizen
> of. Can I apply for a visitor visa at the local visa office?**
>
> If you are applying on paper we recommend that you apply for a visa
> from your home country. However, if you are legally admitted to the
> country you are currently in, you can apply at your nearest visa
> application centre (VAC). The VAC can help make sure your application
> is complete and that all proper documentation is included. You must
> state clearly on your application why you have not applied in your
> normal country of residence.
>
> You can also apply for a visa online.
>
> https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1017&top=16

---

> from within Canada while on a visitor visa?

A multi-entry supervisa valid for ten years or until passport expiry is not issued within Canada.

But if you have been admitted as a visitor on a normal visitor visa (for which six months of stay are normally granted), you may nonetheless apply to extend your stay under the supervisa stream (with the same requirements, e.g. minimum income, medical insurance, etc.). In this case, a visitor record would be issued to allow an additional period of stay for (usually) one or two years.

Unlike a supervisa issued on a counterfoil outside Canada, the visitor record is only valid while you are in Canada. If you leave Canada, the visitor record does not authorize your return to Canada.

If you have a valid multiple entry visa or if you are visa exempt, you may return to a Canadian port of entry and apply to enter Canada again. It will be treated as a new application for admission. The border officer can admit you for another six months (or other periods they think justified). Sometimes, if you have a previously issued extension (visitor record) and have only taken a short trip outside Canada (e.g. to the U.S.), the border officer may re-admit you for the previously authorized extension period; but this is at discretion and not a guarantee. As always, if the border officer is not satisfied that you will follow or have followed immigration law, they can also of course refuse your entry despite your visitor visa or previously issued visitor record.